# Hindi TV series with angry ghost developing affection for single mother and her kids

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror

I remember watching this TV series long ago on Indian television where a  widow or divorced woman moved with her kids into a haunted house with an angry ghost who was not welcoming at the start.

**Genres**: Horror/fantasy

**Plot**: This single mother moves with her kids (I guess two kids; one male, one female) to a new house. Probably the father is dead or she is divorced. The ghost is a grumpy male who was in some job like Navy or Army or something similar when he was alive. He loves his house and scares away occupants but with this family, he gets attached.

A lot of shenanigans happen and the villain of the week type format follows. Villains were sometimes humans and sometimes supernatural.

**Specific episode**: A weird looking guy uses makeup to make his lips look bigger and threatens humanity with a continued solar eclipse unless they fulfill his wishes.

**Language**: Hindi

**Telecast Year**: somewhere in the early 2000s (can be mid-2000s too)

**Country**: India (North Indian to be precise)

**Type**: Live action/coloured

**Character looks:** Ghost used to wear a hat (Indian Army/Navy/Police type). The mother wears Indian traditional (Saree/suit type). Kids were school-going age like 13-16 I guess.

<sub>It was an individual show not part of any horror show like Aahat/Shhh koi hai</sub>

Comment: It sounds like an adaptation of *The Ghost and Mrs. Muir*.

Comment: @OrganicMarble that sounds more like a love story, here the ghost was more of a foster father of kids without romantic tension I guess. I never finished the show so not sure. BUt there might be some inspiration as the ghost did wear a hat or some army/navy type.

Comment: Yeah, I could not find any connection. But your first Plot: paragraph describes that show exactly. The rest of the question, not so much.

Comment: @OrganicMarble may be inspired but due to target demography, they made changes, As this show was more of fantasy/drama for family time type show.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Since "The Ghost and Mrs. Muir" was first written as a novel (1945), adapted into a movie (1947), and then into a TV series (1968), and numerous TV shows have been adapted into foreign markets (countless U.S. shows are essentially adaptations of British shows), it seems reasonable that this is an Indian adaptation of the American classic.

Comment: @AnthonyX agreed, but I could find no proof by googling.

Comment: @OrganicMarble it can be"unofficially inspired by" rather then adaptation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this one is inspired by *The Ghost and Mrs. Muir* or not but I got my answer by digging more.

It's [Captain House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_House) :

> The series is a horror comedy that revolves around a haunted house with an element of fantasy in it. The story revolves around a young widow and her two little children who come to live in the house.

Here is the main lead:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for coming back with the answer!